# android, Sony Z3, 4k video recording

Tags: android, sony, video-recording

Is there any way to enable 4k video recording on Sony Z3 within a custom app?
Cause, getSupportedVideoSizes() returns max resolution 1920x1080.

But the phone itself obviously supports 4k, http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/phones/xperia-z3/features/#camera-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of recording 4K video with a custom app on the Z3.

It's very likely Sony use a custom & private API to control the camera to record 4K.

If it was possible then `getSupportedVideoSizes()` would return a 4K resolution.